# ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in ionic 3

Tags: php, json, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to push registered users details to mysql using php and i get the eror above please help fix.Below are the images of my codes
[php file to push data to mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLsZn.png)

[php config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljmWH.png)

[provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvUiJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

your problem exists in php file. it is returning error instead of valid json response. looking at php error_log will tell you what is the error.